# Not expected fetched objects

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Why is my app not showing the expected number of rows? I am testing my tableView and it is showing perfectly the section titles and the expected rows in the sections, but only if populated from text included in a switch loop. 
In this case, I am using fixed sections and section titles:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 6;
}


+ (NSString*) titleForHeaderForSection:(int) section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0 : return @"Overdue";
        case 1 : return @"Today";
        case 2 : return @"Tomorrow";
        case 3 : return @"Upcoming";
        case 4 : return @"Someday";
        case 5 : return @"Completed";
        //default : return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section no. %i",section + 1];
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [CollapsableTableViewViewController titleForHeaderForSection:section];
}
```

On section `case 2` (Tomorrow),the expected number of rows should be 3, then there are three objects in the core data store. But the result is 0. Here is the used code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int numero = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
    NSLog(@"numero = %d", numero);
    switch (section)
    {
        case 2 : return numero;
        case 3 : return 30;
        default : return 8;
    }
}
```

And here is the simulator screenshot to demonstrate it (void Tomorrow section):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your method. 
At the moment you return ever the count of the number of section and not of the rows in section ;) You forgotten `objectAtIndex:section`

You have to use:

```
[[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] count];
```

enjoy!

Comment: Thank you, but I have updated my code with your proposal and nothing has changed in the log...numero = 0

Comment: and I am sure there are three objects in the core data store

Comment: so, there are others problems in loading fetchedResultsController..need to see all the code.

Comment: than you, but I asked the question again and is already solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064864/fetching-and-sorting-objects-into-sections